# Is there a way that i can combine(or use) resources of my raspeberry pi4 based PC wirelessly?

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, wireless, file-sharing, monitoring

I have a Raspberry pi4-ARM Linux based PC. I want to use my monitor connected to pi sometimes as my dual monitor. i want to do it without changing cables each time I switch back to Linux from Windows. i also want both of them to share memory( extra HDD which is plugged to my PI). And i want this setup to work wirelessly. I have a common Wi-Fi for them. If u can help me with links to some articles it would be appreciated.
I searched for multiple blogs but none gave me exact answer!

Update(including Example) : Consider my pi as a computer with 2 monitors and a hard disk of two tb. Now i want to use those monitors as my secondary monitors and that 2 tb hard disk as my cloud server accessible within my Wi-Fi range....with a constraint of no extra wires connected to my Laptop.

Comment: That might have been possible if your desktop was Linux with X window system. Then you could have beet set it such as second display to draw to VNC server virtual screen instead of some real device, and Pi must run full-screen VNC client to show contents of that virtual screen. Like this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/357959/vnc-server-as-a-virtual-x11-monitor-to-expand-screen-problem . I don't know if similar setup is possible on Windows, though, but now you have an idea to consider.

Comment: Unfortunately cannot use linux on a gaming PC. it would be a waste